# PyTorch and ONNX give different results for compiled model

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, sentiment-analysis, onnx

I have created a sentiment analysis model in PyTorch based on Bert as follows:

```py
12 class BERTGRUSentiment(nn.Module):                                                                                               
   13     def __init__(self,                                                                                                           
   14                  bert,                                                                                                           
   15                  hidden_dim,                                                                                                     
   16                  output_dim,                                                                                                     
   17                  n_layers,                                                                                                       
   18                  dropout=0.0):                                                                                                   
S> 19                                                                                                                                  
   20         super().__init__()                                                                                                       
S> 21                                                                                                                                  
   22         self.bert = bert                                                                                                         
S> 23                                                                                                                                  
   24         embedding_dim = bert.config.to_dict()['hidden_size']                                                                     
S> 25                                                                                                                                  
   26         self.rnn = nn.GRU(embedding_dim,                                                                                         
   27                           hidden_dim,                                                                                            
S> 28                           num_layers = n_layers,                                                                                 
S> 29                           bidirectional = True,                                                                                  
S> 30                           batch_first = True,                                                                                    
S> 31                           dropout = 0 if (n_layers < 2)  else dropout)                                                           
S> 32                                                                                                                                  
   33         self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2, output_dim)                                                                         
S> 34                                                                                                                                  
   35         self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)                                                                                       
S> 36                                                                                                                                  
   37     def forward(self, text):                                                                                                     
S> 38                                                                                                                                  
   39         # text = [batch size, sent len]                                                                                          
S> 40                                                                                                                                  
   41         with torch.no_grad():                                                                                                    
   42             embedded = self.bert(text)[0]                                                                                        
S> 43                                                                                                                                  
S> 44         #embedded = [batch size, sent len, emb dim]                                                                              
S> 45                                                                                                                                  
   46         _, hidden = self.rnn(embedded)                                                                                           
S> 47                                                                                                                                  
S> 48         #hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, emb dim]                                                                 
S> 49         hidden = torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim = 1)                                                            
S> 50                                                                                                                                  
   51         hidden = self.dropout(hidden)                                                                                            
S> 52                                                                                                                                  
S> 53         #hidden = [batch size, hid dim]                                                                                          
S> 54                                                                                                                                  
   55         output = self.out(hidden)                                                                                                
S> 56                                                                                                                                  
S> 57         #output = [batch size, out dim]                                                                                          
S> 58                                                                                                                                  
   59         return output
```

I then compile this model to ONNX as follows:

```py
  1 import model
  2 import torch
  3 from transformers import BertModel                                                                                                 
  4 from tvm import relay                                                                                                              
  5 import sys
  6 sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)                                                                                                     
  7 
  8 bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')                                                                              
  9 embedding_dim = bert.config.to_dict()['max_position_embeddings']                                                                   
 10 
 11 device = "cuda"
 12 
 13 HIDDEN_DIM = 256   
 14 OUTPUT_DIM = 1     
 15 N_LAYERS = 2       
 16 DROPOUT = 0        
 17 
 18 bert = model.BERTGRUSentiment(bert, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM, N_LAYERS, DROPOUT)                                                     
 19 bert.eval()
 20 bert.to(device)                                                                                                                    
 21 
 22 print(f"cuda: {next(bert.parameters()).is_cuda}")                                                                                  
 23 print(f"training: {bert.training}")
 24 
 25 input_name = "text"
 26 input_shape = [embedding_dim]
 27 
 28 example = model.preprocess(model.tokenizer, "it was ok").unsqueeze(0)                                                              
 29 
 30 torch.onnx.export(bert, example, "model.onnx", export_params=True, opset_version=10, do_constant_folding=True, input_names = ['text'], output_names = ['output'])
```

When, however I run the following program to compare outputs:

```py
acc43% tmux attach -t sentiment

    1 import model
    2 import math
    3 import onnxruntime
    4 import numpy as np
    5 from transformers import BertModel
    6 import torch
    7 
    8 bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')                                                                            
    9 
   10 device = 'cuda'
   11 
   12 HIDDEN_DIM = 256
   13 OUTPUT_DIM = 1   
   14 N_LAYERS = 2     
   15 
   16 bert = model.BERTGRUSentiment(bert, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM, N_LAYERS)
   17 bert = bert.to(device)
   18 bert.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth")) 
   19 
S> 20 session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("model.onnx", providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider'])                                        
   21 
   22 while True:
   23     review = input("Provide a review:\n")
   24     tokens = model.preprocess(model.tokenizer, review).unsqueeze(0)
   25     pytorch = torch.sigmoid(bert(tokens))[0, 0]
   26     inputs = {"text": np.array(tokens.cpu())}
   27     out = session.run(None, inputs)[0]
   28     out = 1 / (1 + math.exp(- out))
   29     print(f"torch: {pytorch}, onnx: {out}")
```

I get wildly different results. Could the issues be the dimensions of the ONNX example input? Is there a reason this is the case?